# Are there any non-fault reasons why ECS Fargate could stop/restart my task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm evaluating ECS Fargate for a project where I'm planning to run a stateful server. Are there any reasons (other than host faults, or other non-recoverable errors) why ECS/Fargate would restart or stop my tasks? For example, would it ever try to move tasks onto different hosts or anything like that?

Note: I'm not planning to enable the autoscaling feature so descaling should not be an issue.

Comment: Hey, generally while transferring your resources to different hosts or any other underlying issues you will get a mail from AWS explaining the issue and the consequences in advance. You can decide then how you want to rectify the issue.
Hope this helps!